# Serve dynamic routes with nginx in a NextJS application

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, next.js

I use nginx as my static file server for my NextJS application, in order to test it in dev environment. My application follows a pattern in which I have, normaly, the following routes:

```
someRoute/
    index.tsx
    register.tsx
    [id].tsx
```

My nginx.conf file has the following content:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /register.html;
    }
}
```

What is happening is that, when I create a docker image of the application using nginx, if i try to access `someRoute/register` or `someRoute/123`, I always get the `localhost/index` page. `someRoute/index` works fine, but the other two don't.

My guess is that when I try to navigate to `someRoute/123` nginx expects to find  `123.html` inside `$uri/`, which of course won't happen, since it is a dynamic route. As per `register.html`, I really don't know what's wrong.

How do I get `someRoute/register` and `someRoute/[id]` working?

Comment: I don't understand your question (what your routes looks like and what file nginx should return as an answer to request), but you definitely using `try_files` directive incorrectly. It's syntax in the used form is `try_files <filename1> <filename2> ... URI`. If none of the files from the list exists, nginx will use the last argument as a new URI. Since `/index.html` file always exists, `/register.html` URI will be never used.

Comment: Have you found a solution?